# mouseClick on part of my canvas, mouseOver the canvas and mouseOut the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, mouseevent

I am trying to attach a mouse over and mouse out events for the canvas:

the default canvas is the canvas of the function `drawcircle`.

if the user overs the canvas, it should be changed to the canvas of `drawEllipse` and when he overs out, it should be changed to `drawCircle`.

in addition, I want to print a message to the screen when the user presses the small lightblue circle (alert a message).

I read that I have to define: `mouseup` and `mousedown` for the mouse over and mouse out but I realy don't know how.

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/c4upM/9/

maybe something like:

```
getPressedCanvasPixel('canvas');

function getPressedCanvasPixel(canvasElement) {
    canvas = document.getElementById(canvasElement);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", alertPressedPixel, false);
}

function alertPressedPixel(event) {
    canvas_x = event.pageX;
    canvas_y = event.pageY;
    alert(canvas_x + ' , ' + canvas_y);
}
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery is ok? If so, try something like this:

```
$('#canvas').on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log('enter'); // do your actions
})
.on('mouseleave', function() {
    console.log('exit'); // do your actions
});
```

As for the little circle, you need to save its coorditates and handle mouse click event, you actually do it, so just add checking for coordinates if they are close to your circle.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried what you suggested in jquery but I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/c4upM/12/

about the coordinates of the small circle, how can I do this check? I need to get all of the coordinates of the circle. can you tell me please? then I insert it into a n array and then I will know how to check.

thank you!!

Comment: @AlonShmiel When you hide element `mouseleave` triggered, why do you need 2 canvases? Try my version with one canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/c4upM/14/